# JTextField doesn't allow to enter text

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, swt, swt-awt

I have a quite old plug-in for Eclipse which worked well until to Kepler. On Kepler the jTextFields don't allow to enter text.

I reduced the code to the minimum trying figure out where is problem, but I stuck here.

```
public class BeanDialog extends Dialog
{
   public void open()
   {
      shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());

      Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND | SWT.EMBEDDED);
  composite.setSize(822, 480);
  final java.awt.Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);

      JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
      frame.add(field1);

      shell.pack();
      shell.open();

      Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
      while (!shell.isDisposed() && show) 
      {
         if (!display.readAndDispatch())
         {
            display.sleep();
         }
      }

      parentShell.close();
   }                        
}
```

The text field is properly shown but I cannot enter text. My environment is java SE 7 (1.7.0_51) on a OS X 10.7.5.

The plug-in help me to add very complex custom annotations into the code, so I actually need to fix it.

I have tried using:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
text.pack();
```

and it works, but updating all the code would be a nightmare.

Can anyone provide any advice ?

Comment: Works fine for me using Kepler SR1 on Linux with SWT 4.3

Comment: Thanks, I have to try it on Linux. Any idea about OSX ?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Don't have the hardware to test it.

Comment: I had this problem with SWT 4.5 on my Mac El Capitan, but it worked fine on Linux (Ubuntu). Did anybody solve this problem?